# File wise processing in Hadoop java programming

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I am new to Hadoop.I had installed hadoop and able to compile and run word count example.

I need some info on how to proceed for file wise operation.

I have some data files(a.txt,b.txt,.....) where each file has 100's of lines with time stamps and readings.I want to process these and give value to each file (a-10,b-15,....).

Main problem is order of lines of data is important for processing.

thank you.

Comment: Take a look at a MapReduce tutorial, e.g. http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read each file in its own mapper, you can try [WholeFileInputFormat](http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/WholeFileInputFormat.java?r=3)